# TYPO3 9.5.x with news 7.2.x: Custom properties

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news, typo3-extensions

I've extended TYPO3 9.5.x with news extension 7.2.x with some custom properties.

I used the manual I found [here](http://keinerweiss.de/525-die-extbase-extension-news-um-ein-feld-erweitern.html).

In general, everything works, but somehow the custom properties I created seem to be blank at the frontend. After clearing the cache, everything works again, but after some time the same issue appears again.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe it has something to do that I'm working with TYPO3 9.5.x and the manual is written for TYPO3 7.6.x?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your TCA modifying code (from ext_tables) to /typo3conf/ext/yourEXT/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php

something like this:

```
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

( function( &$tca) {

    $tempColumns = array(
        'NEW_FIELD' => array(
           'exclude' => 0,
           'label' => 'LLL:EXT:yourEXT/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:tx_newsextend_domain_model_news.NEW_FIELD',
           'config' => array(
              'type' => 'check',
              'default' => 0
           ),
        ),
     );

     \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
        'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        $tempColumns
     );

     \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes("tx_news_domain_model_news", 'NEW_FIELD', '', 'after:title');

})( $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've moved the code and going to look the next two days if the issue still happens. If not, I'm going to accept your answer. :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept it last week. It seems to work, the problem is gone. Thank you again!